# compare passwords on register using password_hash()

Tags: php, mysql, php-password-hash

I'm using the password_hash function to secure the user's password on the login page. However, on the register page I ask the user to prompt his password twice, but I can't compare both hashes cause they are different even if the password is the same.

Should I compare both passwords as strings and then hash the password? or what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: What would be the sense of creating a two different hashes for the same password? How would you, later, check the password given?

Comment: You are right, I used to verify the passwords using `$password = hash('sha512', $password);`and them comparing password  and password2 hashes [because the hash is the same in this case]. Since password_hash() salts the password I guess the best approach is to first compare strings [just to verify that the user didn' make a mistake] and then hash it

Comment: In fact, this validation of password equality should be performed by some Javascript at UI level. It makes no sense sending these two values unchecked to the server, for PHP validation. At interface level you may compare them easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `password_hash` is used to hash a password, generating a new salt if necessary (you may pass your own salt, but this is not necessary), while the `password_verify` function is used to compare them (this function uses the salt stored alongside the hash in order to perform the proper comparison).

When creating the passwords, the user provides it twice on plaintext, so all you need to check is `$password1 == $password2`.

If you wish to verify the password obtained from the database, you need to do:

```
$password_hash = <some database query>
if (password_verify($password, $password_hash)) {
    login_success();
} else {
    login_failure();
}
```

You could compare the passwords in the register page the same way, but there's no need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: is always returning false, why?

Comment: How does password_verify knows what salt to use when comparing the password? You mention that the function uses the salt stored alongside the hash in order to perform proper comparison. So is it correct to say that when I initially created a password hash using password_hash() php function, the hash generated will have the salt in the hash as well? For instance, if hash created is abcde1234, then 1234 in the entire hash is actually the salt value? If so, by looking at a hash, can we determine what part is the salt?

Comment: When you call `password_hash("asdf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT );` the result is something like `$2y$10$Nt30j9SFsrquSS2O9/LH5.PM.NaRknICRSqm4wXL6923LrjE.2KR6`. $2y$ indicates the algorithm used, $10$ indicates the complexity of the hash, and the rest contains both the salt and hash. You can see the salt explicitly if you pass it like `echo password_hash("asdf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["salt" => "000000000000000000000"] );` which results in `$2y$10$000000000000000000000uQLi0PtBgw1xsLnDNzk.97zqSqjxGFqq`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to hash the passwords. They are just strings and can be compared as such:

```
if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_verify']) {
    die('Passwords are not the same...');
}
```

You can also hash the real password and then use the `password_verify` function to make sure it is the same. I do not know why you would do that, but there may be a good reason to:

```
$hash   = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$verify = $_POST['password_verify'];
if ( ! password_verify($verify, $hash)) {
    die('Passwords are not the same...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I just wanted to confirm that comparing both passwords wouldn't become a bigger security matter or even a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, @Sverri, but sending these two password values to the server plain text wouldn't be a security issue? What about the possibility of a sniffer?

Comment: Beside, as I said above in other comment, it does not make any sense to me sending these two values to the server, for PHP validation, when it would be much easier validating if they are equal at UI level, using some Javascript code.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida, first, it should travel through HTTPS; that already means no third party can intercept the password in plain text. Checking it with JS user-side is a good idea, but it would still travel in plain text after the verification, and it's always good to re-validate server side.

Comment: If you use HTTPS, it's fine. But you know the difference from practice to theory, I'm sure. Most of the times, this is not what happens. I always apply MD5 to it before sending, and send just one value when it is equal to the other. Then I apply password_hash() to this MD5 value at server side. To check the password at login it is the same: MD5 the password given and then verify it with password_verify against the hash stored. This way I'm always pretty sure that, even without HTTPS, there is no chance to someone spying. May be a bit paranoid, I admit. But it works.

Comment: It's also completely ineffective... If you're worried about a third party intercepting the login, giving them a hash of the password is indistinct from the password; effectively, the md5 _is_ a password. Even if that weren't the issue, md5 is such a weak hash that an attacker would just run a collision attack on the hash you've given them. And if you're not using HTTPS, a MITM can just inject any malicious JS they wanted. This is security by obscurity at best.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida You should **never** trust data that comes from the client (the browser), even if it was validated using Javascript. Any experienced web developer is able to bypass whatever validation the website does (from modifying the Javascript to just skipping the browser entirely and sending the HTTP request themselves).

Comment: I thank you two for the advice. I'll give this some thought.